Forio countor, design
I am trying to familiarise myself with Forio epicenter Contours, in order to create interactive and better design as well as aresponsive "chart bar for investment portfolio simulation. However after playing HTML I could not make it work, any advice or tips how to tackle these kind of problems? What they offer on interface builder is allright, however I see way more could be done with Python, Java etc..
I tried HTML, and to change a code however I am missing smth out.
